# Uninitialized constant error on spree upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am trying to upgrade from spree 0.7 to spree 1.0.7. After successful bundle install I am fetting the following error:

```
/config/initializers/product_review_ratings.rb:12:in `<class:Config>': uninitialized constant Spree::ProductReviewsRatings::Config::PreferenceAccess (NameError)
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config/initializers/product_review_ratings.rb:10:in `<module:ProductReviewsRatings>'
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config/initializers/product_review_ratings.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config/initializers/product_review_ratings.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/polyglot-0.3.4/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/polyglot-0.3.4/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/nish/repos/spree/voylla_website_production/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /home/nish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@spreeTest/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

/config/initializers/product_review_ratings.rb

```
module Spree
  module ProductReviewsRatings
    class Config
      include Singleton
      include PreferenceAccess

      class << self
        def instance
          return nil unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?('configurations')
          ProductReviewsRatingsConfiguration.find_or_create_by_name("Default product reviews and ratings configuration")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to google, but could not find anything

Answer (score 0):

PreferenceAccess was removed from Spree 1.0.0 by this commit:
https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/a4a57db941eeb6329ac9a5de64f2175e33a56f95

You can add [preference_access.rb](http://github.com/spree/spree/blob/df58dd0ae2dfdc3fc93f2b503b099e1396e1940d/core/lib/spree/preference_access.rb) to your application in order to bring that functionality back, however, this will most likely lead to something else breaking.

If possible, you may want to consider porting from SpreeProductReviewsRatings to the [spree_reviews](https://github.com/spree/spree_reviews) extension, which currently supports Spree 1.0 - 2.3.0.beta.